# Creating a JSON output from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, json

I populate an array with the results of three SQL queries. Then I create a temporary table, insert all this data into it then query the table to be able to pass the result as a json array to my Java app (Android).

So.

```
$i=0;
try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT APPID FROM COMMENTROOM WHERE BADGEID=? GROUP BY APPID");
    $stmt->execute(array($badgeID));
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $row2[$i][0] = $row['APPID'];
            $i++;
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        $server_dir = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
        header('Location: http://' . $server_dir);
        exit();
}

for ($i=0; $i<count($row2); $i++)
{
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT APPNAME, MARKETLINK, FILENAME, USERID FROM TABLE_ADS WHERE ID=?");
        $stmt->execute(array($row2[$i][0]));
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $row2[$i][1] = $row['APPNAME'];
                $row2[$i][2] = $row['MARKETLINK'];
                $row2[$i][3] = $row['FILENAME'];
                $row2[$i][4] = $row['USERID'];
            }
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
            $server_dir = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
            header('Location: http://' . $server_dir);
        exit();
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i<count($row2); $i++)
{
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT BADGEID FROM REG_USERS WHERE ID=?");
        $stmt->execute(array($row2[$i][4]));
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $row2[$i][5] = $row['BADGEID'];
            }
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
            $server_dir = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
            header('Location: http://' . $server_dir);
            exit();
    }
}
```

Then finally after I inserted the data from the $row2 array into the temporary table I do

```
try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM TEMP_COMMENTLIST");
    $stmt->execute();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $output[] = $row;
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        $server_dir = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
        header('Location: http://' . $server_dir);
        exit();
    }
print(json_encode($output));
```

The output looks like

```
[[{"APPID":"0000000021","APPNAME":"Enhanced Email","MARKETLINK":"https:\/\/play.google.com\/store\/apps\/details?id=com.qs.enhancedemail","FILENAME":"00000000089_2013-10-23 13:26:38_Enhanced Email.png","USERID":"00000000089","BADGEID":"2626511"},{"APPID":"0000000037","APPNAME":"Mobile....
```

However I think there must be a better solution than messing with this temporary table thing. Is a there a way to create the SAME output from the $row2 array without any more sql queries?

**SOLUTION:**
I mixed hotzu's and SoaperGEM's solution:

```
  $result = array();
try{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT c.APPID, t.APPNAME, t.MARKETLINK, t.FILENAME, t.USERID, c.BADGEID FROM COMMENTROOM c
    INNER JOIN TABLE_ADS t ON t.ID = c.APPID 
    INNER JOIN REG_USERS r ON r.ID = t.USERID 
    WHERE c.BADGEID = ? 
    GROUP BY c.APPID");
    $stmt->execute(array($badgeID));
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    $server_dir = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
    header('Location: http://' . $server_dir);
    exit();
}


echo "[".json_encode($result)."]";
exit();
```

Comment: try to use LEFT JOIN insteed of INNER JOIN

Comment: It's not null what I get it's []. And it is caused by the   WHERE r.BADGEID = ? line, because without it I receive results

Comment: $badgeID is not null and it has records in the db

Comment: yes, the WHERE is wrong, it should be: WHERE c.APPID = ?

Comment: No it's not. You have just removed the most important condition. I am still working on this.

Comment: So, you want to search byREG_USERS.BADGEID? than probably you shouldn't GROUP BY appid... probably you shouldn't group by at all.

Comment: I just changed r.BADGEID to c.BADGEID and it works. Don't you know by any chance why does my result begins like `[{"APPID":"00000000...` instead of `[[{"APPID":"00000000...` ? I manually had to add the brackets to the echo line.

Comment: because the result object isn't in an array. So if you want so, you should put the $result in an array before you stringify it: echo json_encode(array($result))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

Try this:

```
$result = array();
try{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT c.APPID, t.APPNAME, t.MARKETLINK, t.FILENAME, t.USERID, r.BADGEID FROM COMMENTROOM c
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_ADS t ON t.ID = c.APPID 
    LEFT JOIN REG_USERS r ON r.ID = t.USERID 
    WHERE c.APPID = ? 
    GROUP BY c.APPID";
    $stmt->execute(array($badgeID));
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: This gives me integrity constraint violation as the tables should be specified with the columns, like SoaperGEM did it.

Comment: than change the sql query as SoaperGEM did it. I can't see your full table structures... It was just an example

Comment: I know. Your code is superb as well as SoaperGEM. I will try to make it work. Can you check the code I added to my initial question for syntactical mistakes?

Comment: The main problem is, we can't help if we don't see the exact structure and the relations between the tables. If you won't success with my edited code, you should supply the table structures, and the relations between them

Answer (score 1):

This is really more of a SQL question than anything else. Have you never used JOINs in SQL before? All you need to do is something like this:

```
SELECT c.APPID, t.APPNAME, t.MARKETLINK, t.FILENAME, t.USERID, r.BADGEID 
FROM COMMENTROOM c 
INNER JOIN TABLE_ADS t ON c.APPID = t.ID 
INNER JOIN REG_USERS r ON r.ID = t.USERID
```